# Easiest way to format a number with thousand separators to an NSString according to the Locale

Tags: cocoa, string-formatting

I can't seem to find an easy way to do it. The exact thing I need is:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d doodads", n];
```

Where n is an int. So for 1234 I'd want this string (under my locale):

```
@"1,234 doodads"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have recently discovered this one-liner:

```
[@1234567 descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];  // 1,234,567
```

Or in Swift 2:

```
1234567.descriptionWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())     // 1,234,567
```

Swift 3/4:

```
(1234567 as NSNumber).description(withLocale: Locale.current)
```

Formatted per the question:

```
[@(n) descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

Formatted without Objective-C literals:

```
[[NSNumber numberWithInt:n] descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

This is the solution I was looking for when I asked the question. Available since iOS 2.0 and OS X 10.0, documented to return a string version of the number formatted as per the locale provided. `stringValue` is even documented to use this method but passing `nil`.

Seeing as it is my question and this fits my answer best, I am tempted to change the tick, but it seems cruel. *Update* I changed the tick, this answer is *the* answer.

Answer (score 54):

For 10.6 this works:

```
NSNumberFormatter* numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior: NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString *numberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: i]];
```

And it properly handles localization.

Comment: +1 This should be selected answer as in selected answer there is no setFOrmat method available.

Comment: Apple docs say `NSNumberFormatter` definitely has a `setFormat` method. I’d accept this in preference, but I haven't tested it. I'm sure it's better though.

Answer (score 27):

The below doesn't address the locale, but it is a better way (in my opinion) of setting the thousand separator on the number formatter.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormat = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
numberFormat.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;
numberFormat.groupingSeparator = @",";
numberFormat.groupingSize = 3;
```

Comment: Nice if it works, but this is strictly English formatting, not the default locale of the machine.

Comment: You can set the locale property on the NSNumberFormatter

Comment: But you explicitly set the grouping separator to a comma. This is not true of many locales. Also the grouping size is not three in all locales.

Comment: I'm not saying use them together. My answer was actually in response to the other answers suggesting to use setFormatterBehavior and setNumberStyle. I wasn't actually answering the locale part.

Answer (score 2):

Todd Ransom answered this perfectly.

I would just like to add (in a separate comment, so I can show some nicely formatted code), that if you plan to do this regularly, it's worth creating an NSString helper class.

So, create yourself an NSStringHelper.h containing this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (NSStringHelper)

+(NSString*)formatWithThousandSeparator:(NSInteger)number;

@end
```

..and an NSStringHelper.m file containing this:

```
#import "NSStringHelper.h"

@implementation NSString (NSStringHelper)

+(NSString*)formatWithThousandSeparator:(NSInteger)number
{
    //  Format a number with thousand seperators, eg: "12,345"
    NSNumberFormatter* numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior: NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSString *result = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:number]];
    return result;
}

@end
```

This gives you the perfect way to reuse this code in future projects.

```
 #import "NSStringHelper.h"

 NSInteger numOfUsers = 12345;
 NSString* strNumberOfUsers = [NSString formatWithThousandSeparator:numOfUsers];
```

Cool, hey ?

Again, apologies for reposting Todd's answer (which was exactly what I was looking for !), but this is a great way to solve the problem, and have it ready to be used in your future XCode projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: So the absolute easiest way to do this is `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d doodads", [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] autorelease] stringFromNumber:n]]];`? As that is more verbose than I hoped.

Comment: Max Howell: Normally, you would hold on to the number formatter in an instance variable (which you can make an outlet to keep the formatter in a nib), which makes the expression simply `[myFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:n]]`. (Also, you generally should use `NSInteger` and `numberWithInteger:`, not `int` and `numberWithInt:`, to take advantage of greater range on 64-bit machines.)

Comment: I can't get this to work. Even using setHasThousandSeparators:YES changes nothing — no thousand separators.