# Ipad app not showing values after decimal point when German region is selected

Tags: ios, region, catextlayer

In app, which I am developing, I am dealing with the decimal values. I am priting them using CATextLayer. But, when we select Region German from settings of device, it does not show value after decimal point. But when US/UK/AUSTRALIA region is selected, it shows values after decimal point. Please reply if anyone has faced/worked on such issue

Comment: Can you post some code? Did you use the https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: take example in  (English) = 1.08 in German it will be 1,08 means in germany decimal(.) is replaced by comma(,).

Comment: @Michael: No, I am not using NSNumberFormatter. I am just setting string of CATextLayer.text is CATextLayer. [text setstring:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.4g ", [EXPUtils getRoundedFloat:value]]]; Value is float in which I am storing desired value to print.

Comment: @mudit: u siggesting me to manually check for region and then according to it, display value???

Comment: Have you debugged `[EXPUtils getRoundedFloat:value]`? Have you tried using the number formatter?

Comment: @SureshJambhalkar:firstly i am not saying to you do manually checking. i was just giving you the actual info about format of decimal number used in germany. check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9108196/845115)it is useful for you i think.

Comment: @Michael: Here is Definition of getRoundedFloat  +(float) getRoundedFloat:(float) number{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:3];
    [formatter setRoundingMode: kCFNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
    
    NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:number]];
    
    [formatter release];
    return [numberString floatValue];
} If the value generated is 2.5, when german is selected, it shows 2,5 in numberString. But when I return the float value, it returns only 2. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Michael Thanks a lot!!! I got the solution after debugging EXPUtils :)

Comment: @SureshJambhalkar Please provide the solution here. Maybe others face the same problem in the future. (You can answer your question yourself)