# How/where do I use NSNumberFormatter?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

I'm new to code and after reviewing a few answers still need a hand with this.

In my code:

```
func labelInformation(){
     numLabels.text = newLabel.text
}
```

Current result:

> 228500.23

Desired result:

> 228,500.23

How/where do I use NSNumberFormatter?

Comment: you need to use nsnumber formatter

Comment: look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751867/easiest-way-to-format-a-number-with-thousand-separators-to-an-nsstring-according

Comment: Thanks Mr.T, I looked at the link (great ref) but failed to implement...
I have another portion of my xcode project that was formatted correctly for decimals but not for comma separator. an example on my code would be great:
    var primBreed = Double(Int(eggMulYearTextField.text!)!)
    primBreed = dblAnnProd / primBreed
     primBreedLabel.text = String(format:"%.2f", primBreed)

Result: 282258.06
Target: 282,258.06

Comment: Hi Kawwy you need to BOTH vote up AND tick useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
let inputValue = 228500.23

let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()

numberFormatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
numberFormatter.currencySymbol = ""

let outputString = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(inputValue) ?? "0.00"

print(outputString)   // 228,500.23
```